# How can get a list of included records in a Word Mail Merge Document?

Tags: vba, ms-word, mailmerge

I have a Mail Merge Document which is controlled via VBA. After the user selects the records he wants to print, I want these to get a print date set in the database. For that I need a list of the records included in the mail merge.

I tried using the [.Included property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.mailmergedatasource.included), setting `ThisDocument.MailMerge.DataSource.ActiveRecord = wdFirstRecord` (I later removed the `wdFirstRecord` in favour of `1` since it was giving me trouble)
and then checking for `ThisDocument.MailMerge.DataSource.Included` to be true but got a 5852 runtime-error "Object not available". **EDIT:** I used the following code to iterate over the records. When I remove either of the commented .Included statements, I get said error. (The execution does not feel as slow as yesterday anymore, though it is not especially fast.)

```
Function outputRecords(Optional limitRecords = -1)
    With ThisDocument.MailMerge.DataSource
    Dim str
        For currentFieldNameIndex = 1 To .FieldNames.Count
            str = str & .FieldNames(currentFieldNameIndex) & vbTab
        Next
        Debug.Print str

        For currentRecordIndex = 1 To .RecordCount
            If currentRecordIndex <= limitRecords Or limitRecords < 0 Then
                .ActiveRecord = currentRecordIndex
                str = ""
                For currentDataFieldIndex = 1 To .DataFields.Count
                    str = str & .DataFields(currentDataFieldIndex) & vbTab
                Next
                'Debug.Print str
            End If
            '.Included = True
            'Debug.Print .Included
        Next

    End With
End Function
```

**Is there a solution to know which records are selected by the user?**

About my document: After some general computation, the data source is linked to the document using

```
Dim sql As String
sql = "SELECT * FROM `Sheet0$` "
sql = sql & "WHERE ((`" & photoPathHeader & "` > '') AND (`" & photoLastEditHeader & "` >= #" & Format(printFromDate, "yyyy-mm-dd") & "#)) "
sql = sql & "ORDER BY `klasse#name` ASC"
ThisDocument.MailMerge.OpenDataSource _
    name:=ThisDocument.Path & "\" & ThisDocument.Variables("masterDataFileName"), _
    SQLStatement1:=sql, _
    ReadOnly:=True, LinkToSource:=True
```

a dialog where the user can select individual records for printing is shown. I used this code for that:

```
Application.Dialogs(wdDialogMailMergeRecipients).Display
```

And finally, the Mail Merge is executed using

```
ThisDocument.MailMerge.Execute
```

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Clarification please: you say you get an error 5852, but then you seem to iterate successfully over the records. Did you just continue after the error, or what? Hint: if you use ThisDocument, be sure that the MailMerge data source is set up in that document. If your code is in a template and not in the document with the Data Source attached, you would get that error because ThisDocument has no Mail Merge Data Source object. FWIW long ago using ".Included" used to crash Word - it seems OK here in the simple test I just did but perhaps there's still an unsolved problem.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I added the information to the question. I had tested the iteration and .Included seperately. BTW, .Included is not my prefered solution, it's just the only thing I could find which I thought could help.

Comment: Let it take as long as it needs, my main issue is that I can't figure out which rows are checked and which aren't (without actually merging the document). As a side note, at around 10 columns and 1000 rows it takes about one or two minutes to iterate over all of them, which isn't lightning fast but also not too slow either.

Comment: Just to be absolutely sure, since you haven't commented on the proposed answer: it's unclear whether `ThisDocument` is the correct object. If you substitute `ActiveDocument` throughout, does `.Included` still cause an error?

Comment: @CindyMeister As stated below, for some reason I don't get the error anymore. I havr the code in the same document the data fields are inserted into and the source gets linked to. I for myself am quite conservative using `ActiveDocument` since like I understand it, this will refer to the result document after the merge.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @yokki's answer, I was able to combine that with what I know and ended up with the following

```
Sub listIncluded()
    Dim LastRecord As Long
    With ActiveDocument.MailMerge.DataSource

    ' Storing the index of the last record for later use
    .ActiveRecord = wdLastRecord
    LastRecord = .ActiveRecord

    .ActiveRecord = wdFirstRecord
        Do
            Debug.Print .ActiveRecord
            DoEvents
            If .ActiveRecord = LastRecord Then Exit Do
            .ActiveRecord = wdNextRecord
        Loop Until .ActiveRecord > LastRecord ' Note this will never be satisfied and the loop will always be exited via the Exit Do statement
    End With
End Sub
```

I find the [WdMailMergeActiveRecord enumeration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.wdmailmergeactiverecord) a bit confusing but this works.

The original answer threw a `5853 Invalid parameter` error on the `wdNextRecord` if the last included record had already been reached and was not equal to the last record overall (i.e. the last record was not included). I circumvented this issue by storing the index of the last record into a local variable and using that to check if the last included record was reached.

Thank you very much to everyone who helped!

As briefly pointed out in a comment, I already have a list of all the
data in the data source as an array since I also use it in other parts
of the script. I used the following statement for that

```
numRows = wks.Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count
masterData = wks.Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Offset(RowOffset:=1).Resize(RowSize:=numRows).Value
```

`wks` refers to an Excel worksheet object.

Answer (score 1):

This Answer is based on the comments so far.

1. I do not get the problem with .Included here unless ThisDocument is the wrong document. However, since your loop code does not appear to throw an error when accessing other members of ThisDocument.MailMerge.DataSource it is not obvious what is wrong. However, I don't think you need to use .Included.
2. I see an immediate slowdown as soon as I try to access any of the .Datasource.DataFields items. I do not know why that is. There is a delay for each access, not just the first access for each record. The one idea I had is that as soon as you change the active record, Word refreshes the values of the merge fields in the main document, and that might cause a problem, particularly if Word needed to access the printer driver for some reason. But nothing I tried (e.g. change the View to Draft) changes that.
3. You don't really need .Included because you can iterate the records like this:

   ```
   With ActiveDocument.MailMerge.DataSource
     previousRecord = 0
     .ActiveRecord = wdFirstRecord
     While .ActiveRecord <> previousRecord
       previousRecord = .ActiveRecord
       Debug.Print .ActiveRecord ' (just lists the record number)
       previousRecord = .ActiveRecord
       .ActiveRecord = wdNextRecord
       DoEvents ' advisable if you need to stop the code
     Wend
   ```

   If you need to iterate *all* the records then you need to use wdFirstDataSourceRecord and wdNextDataSourceRecord instead.
4. The only way I was able to speed up access to the data was to modify the document to include all the fields I wanted to list, then get the values from the document rather than from .DataSource.Datafields. Personally I do not think modify the Mail Merge main document is ideal - in particular, something might stop you from inserting material at the beginning, as I have done. But my test code (needs more error trapping etc. is like this):

   ```
   Sub checkincluded()
   Dim b As Word.Bookmark
   Dim bVMMFC As Boolean
   Dim bSFC As Boolean
   Dim i As Integer
   Dim previousRecord As Long
   Dim p As Word.Paragraph
   Dim r As Word.Range

   With ActiveWindow.View
     bSFC = .ShowFieldCodes
     .ShowFieldCodes = False
   End With

   With ActiveDocument.MailMerge
     bVMMFC = .ViewMailMergeFieldCodes
     .ViewMailMergeFieldCodes = False

     With .DataSource
       Set r = ActiveDocument.Range(0, 0)
       Set p = ActiveDocument.Range(0, 0).Paragraphs.Add


       For i = 1 To .FieldNames.Count
         If i > 1 Then
           r.Text = vbTab
           r.Start = p.Range.End - 1
           r.End = p.Range.End - 1
         End If
         r.Fields.Add r, WdFieldType.wdFieldMergeField, .FieldNames(i), False
         r.Start = p.Range.End - 1
         r.End = p.Range.End - 1
       Next
       r.Start = 0
       r.End = p.Range.End - 1
       Set b = r.Bookmarks.Add("recorddata")
       Set r = Nothing

       previousRecord = 0
       .ActiveRecord = wdFirstRecord
       While .ActiveRecord <> previousRecord
         previousRecord = .ActiveRecord
         Debug.Print .ActiveRecord, b.Range.Text
         previousRecord = .ActiveRecord
         .ActiveRecord = wdNextRecord
         DoEvents
       Wend
       b.Delete
       Set b = Nothing
       p.Range.Text = ""
       Set p = Nothing
     End With
     .ViewMailMergeFieldCodes = bVMMFC
   End With

   ActiveWindow.View.ShowFieldCodes = bSFC

   End Sub
   ```
5. Finally, it is probably worth pointing out that there are other ways to exclude records, e.g. using NEXT, NEXTIF, SKIP and SKIPIF fields. But that is perhaps another question.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. 
1. I tried it again and for some reason, it stopped giving me the error. I don't know why.

3. If I try your code with the last record unchecked, it returns all indices as expected, but also a 5853 Invalid parameter error. It does work fine if the last record is checked. This helped me very much.

4. To be honest, I don't fully understand what you did here but since I already have all the data in an array using 'masterData = wks.Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Offset(RowOffset:=1).Resize(RowSize:=numRows).Value' all I need are said indices.